# Are Ukrainian civilians forced to fight against their will?

Tags: armed-conflict, military, ukraine, conscription

Multiple European newspapers stated that the Ukrainian government was doing everything in its power to allow the Ukrainian civilians to flee the country safely. I was under the impression that Ukrainian civilians who are currently taking part in the military conflict against Russia willingly chose to do so.

However recent reports from the Council of Europe Commissioner for Human Rights indicate that a lot of Ukrainian civilians are forced to join the military, under prison or death threats. The civilians are apparently forced to enroll based on their gender; mostly males between 18 and 60 and even trans women.

The Ukrainian military would deny these civilians the right to cross the border and flee the country. They would check civilians' cars at checkpoints to find civilians physically able to use weapons and forcefully enroll them in the armed conflict.

So are Ukrainian civilians really free to flee the country? Or are some of them forced (under prison or death threats) to participate in a military conflict?

**Edit**

Whether conscription is scandalous or not is opinion-based and beyond the scope of this question. What I'm trying to know is whether all Ukrainian civilians (whatever their gender, age, or ethnicity) are free to flee the armed conflict in Ukraine, or whether some or all of them are forced in any way to remain in the country to take part in the armed conflict.

Comment: This question is phrased as if conscription was something scandalous. Although few countries still practice active conscriptions, most of the world still has laws on the book which permit the government to conscript any able-bodied citizens (in most cases only men) in times of war. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription

Comment: @Philipp - Well, it arguably is. There were quite a lot of protests about it in the USA during the Vietnam War, for instance.

Comment: @Obie2.0 There is a difference when people are being conscripted to fight in a foreign conflict and when they are being conscripted to fight in their own country to defend against a foreign invasion.

Comment: Whether conscription is scandalous or not is opinion-based and beyond the scope of this question. What I'm trying to know is whether all ukrainian civilians (whatever their gender, age, or ethnicity) are free to flee the armed conflict in Ukraine or if some or all of them are forced in any way to remain in the borders to take part in the armed conflict.

Comment: As a note I remember hearing lots of reports that women and children had been allowed to flee but men in the 18-60 age group had to stay to defend the country. At least from what I have seen the reports seem pretty common and not something anyone is trying to hide

Comment: "recent reports from the Council of Europe Commissionner for Human Rights indicate that a lot of Ukrainian civilians are forced to join the military". If you've actually read those reports then you know the answer. This question doesn't seem in good faith or is unclear what it's really asking.

Comment: @Fizz I don't know about where you live, but in Europe we read different versions of the same stories depending on the newspaper which publish them. In this case, I just recently read about the visit of the Council of Europe Commissionner for Human Rights in Ukraine and some parts of this article seemed to contradict what I already read in past articles. That's what I'm really asking: are Ukrainian civilians really free to flee the armed conflict in Ukraine or are they in any way forced to take a part in it ?

Comment: @JoeW - Yes, there is. But there is an argument that the second is worse: how moral is it, really, to attempt to obligate people who legitimately fear for their lives and would be considered refugees in any other country (if not internally displaced refugees in their own country) to put their lives in very serious danger instead of trying to protect themselves and their loved ones as best they can? It might not be *unusual*, but whether it is *right* is quite another question.

Comment: Note that some major international organizations such as IFOR (the International Fellowship of Reconciliation) view conscription under such circumstances (or even in general) as a Bad Thing and actively advocate against in the UN, and the UN itself (through the Human Rights Council) recognizes rights such as conscientious objection in general.

Comment: @Obie2.0 A country that is being invaded doesn't have any good choices, if they let everyone who can flee do so there is a higher chance that more people who can't flee and can't defend themselves will just end up dying.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think a general discussion about whether conscription qualifies as an immoral or moral measure would deserve its own question, as I do not see how it provides an answer to this specific question.

Comment: Please provide a link to the human rights report you're mentioning.

Comment: @Panzercrisis I did not find the exact article I read earlier, but I provided an answer with two articles which might answer the question, one having been shared by the Council of Europe Commissionner for Human Rights herself.

Comment: @Silicium But morality is important here. Ukraine does have a law about conscription. If the existence of that law is moral, but enforcing it is "being forced" - can we say that civilians in Ukraine are *being forced* to refrain for stealing? It's the same situation - there's a law that prescribes imprisonment as a punishment for a certain action. Only in one case the action is theft, and in the other - draft dodging. Of course, situation would be different regarding civilians not legally draftable, but from the quotes in the answer you posted - that doesn't seem to be the case?

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov Your comment deserves to be posted as an entirely separate question as discussing the morality of conscription is an interesting, yet incredibly specialized topic which should not be debated in the comments of this question. This question is merely about the existence of any type of coercion (conscription or any other mean) on ukrainian civilians to become active participants in the armed conflict which is currently happening on Ukraine soil.

Comment: As written, I see this as misrepresenting the nature of the draft. This is not a board for *advocacy*, and having a draft is accepted in principle by the international community.

Comment: The question is whether these are civilians fleeing, or conscripted soldiers deserting. I doubt Ukraine is giving civilians guns and dropping them into active combat zones; they're collecting people to train them as soldiers. By the time they are fighting, they shouldn't be civilians anymore.

Comment: @Obie2.0 whether able-bodied Ukrainian men between the ages of 18 and 60 are being denied the right of conscientious objection is a separate question from that of whether they're being forbidden from leaving the country.  Maybe conscientious objectors are recognized.  Maybe they're allowed to leave.  Maybe they're required to stay and do other work.

Comment: Why need to use loaded language rather than just say drafting or conscription? It puts in doubt the claim that the question is merely about their existence.

Comment: will is tricky question, with enouphpropaganda, masses will want to do something, but is it real their will?

Comment: My understanding is that there were more volunteers than capacity  available. Source: Ukraincast podcast by BBC

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To quote Wikipedia on [conscription in the Ukrainian army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armed_Forces_of_Ukraine#Conscription):

> In October 2013 President Yanukovich ended conscription in Ukraine, at the time 60% of Ukraine's forces were composed of professional soldiers.[82] However, due to the 2014 Russian military intervention in Ukraine conscription, as well as a partial mobilization, was reinstated in 2014.[83] Ukraine has modified the age group of males eligible for conscription for 2015 from 18–25 to the 20–27 age group.[84]

> After serving out the term of service Ukraine's conscripts become part of the inactive reserve and are eligible to be recalled for mobilization until they reach age 55, age 60 for officers. Due to the war in Donbas Ukraine has instated a partial mobilization to fill needed positions in its armed forces, recalling conscripts who have served before, because of the war many conscripts have also been forced to serve longer than their original 18-month term of service.[85] It was planned that in 2015 Ukraine would undergo three waves of partial mobilization, this would have allowed new troops to replace those serving longer than their original term of service.[86]

And further:

> All medical workers in Ukraine, regardless of gender, are eligible to be called up for service in case of a national emergency.

In other words, all able-bodied men, as well as the medical personnel (regardless of gender) are legally obliged to take part in the fighting (*mobilization* in the quotes before) - I suppose that there is a motivated order by the president to this end. Naturally (and understandably), there are many men who flee, in order to protect their lives, and the authorities are trying to force them to return and join the army. The situation is not unusual in the times of military conflict, and whether one calls them *deserters*, *draft dodgers* or *civilians fleeing fighting* is a matter of personal perspective.

Comment: This is the best answer, as it answers the original question and provides objective, non-self-contradictory information

Comment: This answer (and similarly the original question) seems to mix up the concept of the governemt requiring able-bodied men to be available for conscription and actually making them join the fighting. Ukraine has approximately 40 million inhabitants so there are somewhere in the range of 10 to 15 million able-bodied men that are required to stay in Ukraine and that the government could conscript into the armed forces. But only about 300.000 of them (less than 5%) actually are in the armed forces.

Comment: @quarague indeed, being forced to stay in the country, and being forced to fight are not the same thing. The question asks about both: *So are Ukrainian civilians really free to flee the country? Or are some of them forced (under prison or death threats) to participate in a military conflict?* The answer to both is clear: no, they are not to flee the country. Yes, some of them are forced to fight, since, if they receive the mobilization order, they cannot refuse to obey.

Comment: @quarague Aside: 300,000 is likely an incorrect number - In summer Zelensky himself promised 1 million strong offensive. Your number also doesn't doesn't square with Russian mobilization that called the same 300,000 only as reinforcements - in addition to those who are already participating in the conflict.

Comment: I didn't search for current numbers in the Ukrainian military, so the 300.000 currently is probably too low. But my point remains. In your comment you first write about [all] civilians being able to flee and then about **some of them** forced to fight. You answer is written in a way that completely blurs this distiction. Ie 'the authorities are trying to force them to return [that is all of them] and join the army [that applies only to a few]'.

Answer (score 9):

### No.

Ukraine is drafting civilians into their military, as it is commonly accepted by international law. The military is then forced to fight. A small difference, but a difference.

- The legitimate Ukrainian government has military conscription. It allows [conscientious objector](https://www.ohchr.org/sites/default/files/Documents/Issues/RuleOfLaw/ConscientiousObjection/2019/Ukraine.pdf) status, but apparently this is significantly harder than other democracies made it in recent decades. Not necessarily harder than they made it during the Cold War.
- The self-declared republics in the Donbas seem to be [conscripting fighters](https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-april-10), too. They seem to have considerably fewer safeguards, and they are assumed to be working at the orders of the Russian government. So Russia is forcibly drafting *Ukrainian* citizens to fight against their legitimiate government, which is not covered by international law.

Comment: Nobody in that republics has elected the curent ukrainian government, so tallking about legitimity of that government on that teritory is a bit problematic. Also this answer seems to be based on whataboutism, so don´t se how it answering the question.

Comment: @convert, the header of the question talked about Ukrainian citizens being drafted to fight, only the main text went into details. A complete answer to the header mentions *all* governments which draft them, and any answer regarding the self-declared republics should point out that they are self-declared and not widely recognized.

Comment: @convert Conscripting people on conquered territory (this definitely includes the territory conquered at least in 2022, possibly also in 2014) is an internationally recognized war crime. The answer also definitely answers the title.

Comment: War Resistors International [reports](https://wri-irg.org/en/programmes/world_survey/country_report/en/Ukraine) that "The right to conscientious objection only applies to members of officially registered religious denominations who forbid their members to bear arms." The government has decreed a list of accepted religious denominations: Seventh Day Adventists, Baptists, Adventists-Reformists, Jehovah's Witnesses and the Charismatic Christian Church.

Comment: @ccprog, hence my 'significantly harder' remark. But I'm old enough to recall how this changed in the West, a generation ago.

Comment: @o.m. The point is that the right is denied to anyone who is not a member of one of the organised religions. The term "conscience" is not recognised to be a function of one's unique personality, but only as a prescription by an outside force. With all the harshness in interrogating objectors in the West in the 70s, the basic premise was always that the reason could lay within the person of the objector, not in a membership. (My personal experience was 1986 in Germany - "not necessarily harder" would be a bold-faced lie.)

Comment: @ccprog, Germany reformed the "Gewissensprüfung" in 1983. I know several people who objected during or after their service (i.e. while they were liable for reserve recall) and they had to *document* their personal convictions with more than just a personal statement. Affilation with organized religion was one of the common ways. They would then be quizzed as to the depth and sincerity of their convictions.

Answer (score 6):

Although I did not find the exact newspaper article I read earlier, I found [an article from *The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/global-development/2022/mar/09/ukraine-urged-to-take-humane-approach-as-men-try-to-flee-war) which seems to indicate that the Ukrainian government does indeed prevent male Ukrainian civilians aged 18 to 60 from fleeing the country. However, the article also specifies that they are not, at this point in time, forced to take an active part in the armed conflict.

> The UN has urged Ukraine to take a “compassionate and humane” approach
> to the enforcement of martial law after reports of Ukrainian men
> defying orders to stay and attempting to cross into neighbouring
> countries to claim asylum.
>
> Men of conscription age, aged 18 to 60, were banned from leaving
> Ukraine after the Russian invasion on 24 February but there have been
> multiple reports of men with Ukrainian citizenship trying to cross
> into Hungary, Poland and Romania. It is unclear how many have been
> allowed to pass.
>
> The Ukrainian government is not forcing men to fight, only remain in
> the country, but there are fears of enforced conscription if the
> violence continues.

I also found [this article](https://frontnews.eu/en/news/details/30680) shared on Twitter by Dunja Mijatovic, the Council of Europe Commissioner for Human Rights, which explicitly states that "all men between the ages of 18 and 60 are required by martial law to remain in Ukraine":

> During my recent visit to Ukraine, I was also told that some
> transgender people have difficulty leaving the country. For example,
> this is the case with several transgender women who are blocked in
> Ukraine because they have not completed the process of legal gender
> recognition, and therefore the gender markers on their identity
> documents remain male, while all men between the ages of 18 and 60 are
> required by martial law to remain in Ukraine. More generally,
> authorities in both Ukraine and the border countries should address
> the particular vulnerability of transgender people who need to leave
> the country so they can do so safely.

Based on these two articles, it does not seem that Ukrainian civilians are currently forced to fight in Ukraine at this point in time, although the situation might very well evolve in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score -1):

**No**, looks like into the sixth month of the war there are still enough volunteers ready to fight on the free will.

[The New York Times writes](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/01/08/world/europe/ukraine-russia-volunteers-chechens-tatars.html?unlocked_article_code=wXUVnP9r-xU8nEo1WBjKdG9OFuG7ij5wgl_N_UYh57LN_V4T25T-Sjm-18NHO-HZQWfTeWcfb9OSu__toK1ZJhC7uEo1o7C6tDkkHdDk6DgHLjjNtfonu-lZOBjORkwhfCGDu3dtPcbwqFPG5yqQqA54Ou2Xb5ve31TxbIx_LK863NRGlXmfUnHlbhyj-n0cZeb87lmwsFHSlj_nZoXV1-KPSanFZWFnFmn__ntozTnERqdwLlPKrr2ti66bcJBe5kzFlbnJOKTtbFV2YKB-H2yY42D-iEOIDwwdsoJh_Z1PS-DcZ69GEyy94CyEXzIg0NUtSBQ3-JyW0aCuRHdFjC1nwafrthTRXQwrChaps-1EK5uYr1fjwhQ&smid=share-url) that there are not just local but even foreign volunteers coming, even from Russia, even from Chechnya, whom Ukraine does not need but anyway shows an effort to accept. It may be possible to find some Ukrainians that do not want to fight and choose to flee instead, but seems no big need to care about those so far. Looks like the lack of armament is still much more the limiting factor for Ukraine.

From the other side, most of the countries have the legal option to call every single man to defend the country, and it is mandatory to respond to the call. For instance, USA is commonly seen as a country with the professional army, but they have the [selective service](https://www.usa.gov/selective-service) also. This may not sound nice but if this is a violation of human rights, this violation is present I think in about any country in the world.